# Snooker Android Application

Tags: android, camera

I am working currently on my final year project / dissertation for the university and I have a "crazy" idea for it.
I was thinking of designing an android app for Snooker players, different bars or tournaments, an app that will use the mobile camera to detect every movement and change on the table and in the same time will keep the score for the players without any human input.
I want to know if it is an impossible thing. If it is plausible I really need some ideas, advices from where to start.

I got to say that I have some experience in Android development and I already started to read a lot of articles, projects about the shape detection, color detection and edge detection.

Thank you !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions on SO are programming related problems not system design or architecture. These kind of questions are likely to cause debate.

Comment: May be a good question for [AndroidEnthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/) or [programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)